# custom cell and custom height for each

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cgrect

I output 4 custom cells via the switch function now I need to output either a dynamic height value or a fixed height value for each of them. I like both, as their height is always static.

I subscribed to The `uiСollectionviewВelegateFlowLayout` Protocol and found how to change the height of all cells

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: 357, height: 600)
        return size
```

to override the height of individual cells I use the function

```
cell.frame = CGRect(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
```

but it doesn't work, "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context"

what should I do in this case? what function to use?

full code below

```
// main protocols UICollectionView
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // width and height for cell in collectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: 357, height: 600)
        return size
    }


    //margins for cell in collectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


            var cell: UICollectionViewCell!

            switch indexPath.row {
            case 1:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? secondCollectionViewCell
                cell.frame = CGRect(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)

            case 2:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? cellThirdCollectionViewCell

            case 3:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "fourthCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? fourthCollectionViewCell

            default:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? imageModelCollectionViewCell
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 1:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 200)
        case 2:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 300)
        case 3:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 400)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell: UICollectionViewCell!

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 1:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath)
                as? firstCollectionViewCell


        case 2:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
                as? secondCollectionViewCell

        case 3:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath)
                as? thirdCollectionViewCell

        default:
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)
                as? imageModelCollectionViewCell
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

completely solves the problem
don't forget add

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
}
```

p.s. If You get an error with "`collectionView.delegate = self`" is a possible reason that you are working in a `viewController` and not in a collectionViewController

You need to add `IBOutlet`

Answer (score 0):

you can use array of height and retrieve cell height based on indexPath.

```
let heightArray = [90,400,100,70]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

                return CGSize(width: 357, height: heightArray[indexPath.row])

        }
```

Comment: how can I enable height change in one of the cases. 

I need to change the height of some cells, leaving the rest unchanged

Comment: you can decide in sizeForItemAt.ex if indexPath.row == 1 retune height 100 else return height 200.if you want to layout cell based on content better is go with Pinterest layout(https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Comment: Thanks for the link. 
I don't need the switch on-OFF function I need for each cell in the case to prescribe a separate height

in case 1 the height will be 100
in case 2, the altitude of 300
case 3 height 90

All cells are displayed simultaneously. One by one
unfortunately, I have not been able to succeed yet

Comment: Can you  upload image what kind of result you want.

Comment: update post.

all cells are custom and output sequentially in the switch function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your function `func collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` to something like this?

```
let cellHeights = [ 90, 400, 100, 70 ]

// width and height for cell in collectionView
func collectionView( _ view: UICollectionView, 
                     layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                     sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath ) -> CGSize 
{
    return CGSize( 
        width: view.bounds.size.width, 
        height: cellHeights[indexPath.row] 
    )
}
```

Also, casting the result of `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` to a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass has no effect in your code...

I might change it to something like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
    // map row numbers to cell reuse identifiers...   
    let ids = [ 
        0: "secondCell", 
        1: "thirdCell", 
        2: "fourthCell" 
    ]

    // look up the reuse identifier for the row we want; if none found (subscript call returns `nil`), use `"imageCell"`
    let reuseID = ids[indexPath.row] ?? "imageCell"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell( withReuseIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```